# Number of arguments passed to thread in windows

Tags: multithreading, arguments

In C++/C#/Java we can start the thread with function that accepts some arguments. In WinAPI we start the thread with function that accepts only void*.
How many arguments are passed really to real windows threads? Maybe many arguments are turned into void* that points on some struct?

Answer (score 0):

At the core of most threading APIs is a function pointer to execute and a void* parameter that lets you provide some data to the executing function.  The void* typically points to some object instance that the thread function then casts into the known object type to use.  This, however, is ripe for programmer error.

The higher level APIs that you mention (std::thread in C++, Thread in Java, etc) are doing this under the hood and providing you convenient, type-safe APIs to ensure you can't mess it up.